# Altair: Controlling tick counts for binned axis

Tags: python, plot, histogram, altair, vega-lite

I'm trying to generate a histogram in Altair, but I'm having trouble controlling the tick count for the axis corresponding to the binned variable (x-axis). I'm new to Altair so apologies I'm missing something obvious here. I tried to look for whether others had faced this kind of issue but didn't find an exact match.

The code to generate the histogram is

```
alt.Chart(df_test).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('x:Q', bin=alt.Bin(step=0.1), scale=alt.Scale(domain=[8.9, 11.6])),
    y=alt.Y('count(y):Q', title='Count(Y)')
).configure_axis(labelLimit=0, tickCount=3)
```

`df_test` is a Pandas dataframe - the data for which is available [here](https://www.transfernow.net/dl/test_csv).

The above code generates the following histogram. Changing `tickCount` changes the y-axis tick counts, but not the x-axis.

[image]

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a more convenient way to do this using `bin=`, but one approach is to use `transform_bin` with `mark_rect`, since this does not change the axis into a binned axis (which are more difficult to customize):

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.movies.url

alt.Chart(source).mark_rect(stroke='white').encode(
    x=alt.X('x1:Q', title='IMDB Rating', axis=alt.Axis(tickCount=3)),
    x2='x2:Q',
    y='count()',
).transform_bin(
    ['x1', 'x2'], field='IMDB_Rating'
)
```

[image]

You might notice that you don't get the exact number of ticks, this is because there is rounding to "nice" values, such as multiple of 5 etc. I couldn't turn this off even when setting `nice=False` on the scale, so another approach in those cases is to pass the exact tick values `values=`.

```
alt.Chart(source).mark_rect(stroke='white').encode(
    x=alt.X('x1:Q', title='IMDB Rating', axis=alt.Axis(values=[0, 3, 6, 9])),
    x2='x2:Q',
    y='count()',
).transform_bin(
    ['x1', 'x2'], field='IMDB_Rating'
)
```

[image]

Be careful with decimal values, these are automatically displayed as integers (even with `tickRound=False`), but in the wrong position (this seems like a bug to me so if you investigate it more you might want to report on the Vega Lite issue tracker.

Comment: Thank you! This solves my problem perfectly. The `stroke=white` was important to make it look like a histogram, otherwise it seemed the bars were overlapping with each other.

Comment: And it seems you don't strictly need `mark_rect` - using `mark_bar` works too as long as you bin the variable using `transform_bin` (and use `stroke=white` as in the previous comment).

Comment: @PJMU Some axis setting like `nice` might be respected when altair is updated to VegaLite 5.0 (which will happen soon) as this PR was merged in that release https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/pull/7192